# python how to access to serialized object contained in zip file

Tags: python, zip, pickle

I'm storing pickled objects inside a zip file.

Now I want to use one of those object without extracting the file from zip. Is it possible ?

I tried something like this, but it is not working:

the zip file:

```
my_archiv.zip
|--object1.p
|--object2.p
```

The code to try to import one of the objects:

```
import os
import zipfile
import pickle as pk

obj1_path = zipfile.Path("my_archiv.zip", "object1.p")
data = pk.load(open(str(obj1_path),'rb'))
```

But "No such file or directory"
any help ?